# illegal start of expression java boolean

Tags: java, netbeans-8

There is a problem with public boolean vlozVec(Vec vec) where is a illegal start of expression error. I don't know how to fix it a I don't have much time so please help me guys. I need to send it as soon as possible and this is last problem I can't solve after hours of work. Thank you!!

```
package eu.pedu.adv16s._4_1800.macv03_macura.logika;

import eu.pedu.adv16s_fw.game_txt.IBag;
import eu.pedu.adv16s_fw.game_txt.IItem;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;


/**
 * Třída Inventar - představuje inventář pro sbírané věci.
 * Kapacita je omezena na dvě věci.
 *
 * @author    Viktor Mačura
 * @version   semestrální práce 4IT101 ZS 2015/2016
 */
public class Inventar implements IBag
{
    private Map<String, Vec> seznamVeci;
    static final int kapacita = 2;

/**
 * Vytvoření inventáře, věci se ukládají do seznamu 
 * pomocí HashMap
 */
public Inventar()
{
    seznamVeci = new HashMap<>();



/**
 * Vkládá věci do inventáře.
 * @param Vec vkládáná věc
 * @return boolean true pokud je v inventáři místo,
 * false pokud v něm není místo
 */
public boolean vlozVec(Vec vec)
{
    if (seznamVeci.size() < kapacita) 
    {
        seznamVeci.put(vec.getNazev(), vec);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * Odebírá věc z inventáře.
 * @param String název věci
 * @return Vec pokud je věc v inventáři, odebere ji a vrátí na ni odkaz,
 * pokud neni, vrátí null
 */
public Vec seberVec(String nazev)
{
    Vec odebirana = null;
    if (seznamVeci.containsKey(nazev)) 
    {
        odebirana = seznamVeci.get(nazev);
        seznamVeci.remove(nazev);
    }
    return odebirana;
}

/**
 * Zjišťuje, jestli je požadovaná věc v inventáři.
 * @param String název věci
 * @return boolean true pokud je v inventáři, false pokud není v inventáři.
 */
public boolean obsahujeVec(String nazev) 
{
    return seznamVeci.containsKey(nazev);
}

/**
 * Vrací odkaz na požadovanou věc.
 * @param String název věci
 * @return Vec
 */
public Vec getVec(String nazev) 
{
    return seznamVeci.get(nazev);
}

@Override
public int getCapacity() 
{
    return kapacita;
}

@Override
public Collection<Vec> getItems() 
{
    return seznamVeci.values();

}
}
```

Comment: Why does the Inventar method stop abruptly (no closing } ). In fact loads of the methods do

Comment: Indent your code and you should be able to spot the error.

Comment: Questions that post broken code and say something like "please fix it please" are **off-topic**.

Answer (score 0):

You can't embed a method in your constructor. Close the constructor before your method declaration.

```
public Inventar()
{
    seznamVeci = new HashMap<>();
} // <-- add this.
public boolean vlozVec(Vec vec) // <-- before this...
```